# WWW WebRequest UriFormatException: URI scheme must start with a letter and must consist of one of

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, web, server

I've been getting this error in versions 2017.2.0f3 and 2017.2.1f1 whenever running the line below from the class listed, however it works perfectly in 5.5.0.f3

```
WWW request = new WWW(m_host, bytes, HashtableToDictionary<string, string>(postHeader));
```

ERROR:

```
UriFormatException: URI scheme must start with a letter and must consist of one of alphabet, digits, '+', '-' or '.' character.
System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String uriString)
System.Uri.ParseUri (UriKind kind)
System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape)
System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString)
```

Class producing Error:

```
public class ServerRequest<T> : BaseServerRequest
{
    public string Game;
    public string Content;

    [NonSerialized]
    public bool Successful;
    [NonSerialized]
    public ServerResponseData<T> Response;

    private string m_host;
    private MonoBehaviour owner;

    private bool m_finished = false;
    private bool m_running = false;

    public override object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ServerRequest(Dictionary<string, object> content, string game, string host, MonoBehaviour owner)
    {
        SetContent(content);
        Game = game;
        m_host = host;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public IEnumerator Process()
    {
        Debug.Log("Sending Data...");
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        string json = TinyJson.JSONParser.ToJson(this);
        Debug.Log("Sending Json...\n" + json);

        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(json);

        Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
        postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");
        postHeader.Add("Content-Length", json);


        WWW request = new WWW(m_host, bytes, HashtableToDictionary<string, string>(postHeader));
        yield return request;

        if (request == null)
        {
            Successful = false;
        }
        else if (request.error != null)
        {
            Successful = false;
            Debug.LogError(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Successful = true;
            Debug.Log("Response Text: " + request.text);

            string responseJson1 = request.text.ReplaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n").ReplaceAll("\\t", "\\\\t");
            Debug.Log("Response Text2: " + responseJson1);
            Response = TinyJson.JSONParser.FromJson<ServerResponseData<T>>(responseJson1);

            Debug.Log("Response: ");
            Debug.Log("\tContent: " + Response.Content);
            Debug.Log("\tSuccessful: " + Response.Successful);
            Debug.Log("\tMessage: " + Response.Message);
        }

        m_finished = true;
    }

    public static Dictionary<K, V> HashtableToDictionary<K, V>(Hashtable table)
    {
        return table
          .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
          .ToDictionary(kvp => (K)kvp.Key, kvp => (V)kvp.Value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Response: Successfull = {0}, Content = {1}", Successful, Response);
    }

    public override string ToJson()
    {
        return string.Format("{{ \"Game\": \"{0}\", \"Content\": {1} }}", Game, Content);
    }

    public override bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (!m_running)
        {
            m_running = true;
            owner.StartCoroutine(Process());
        }
        return !m_finished;
    }

    public override void Reset()
    {
        // Nope
    }

    public void SetContent(Dictionary<string, object> content)
    {
        Content = TinyJson.JSONParser.ToJson(content);
    }
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before and been able to fix it?

Comment: URI scheme is the url you're sending request to (in this case the value of `m_host`)

Comment: Scheme, for example, is "http" or "https". Of course a number of other schemes exist, although for web I imagine you're using http or https.

Comment: And as I've already told someone else today, unless you are certain of the content you're putting into your JSON, it's best to use a serializer. If `Game` or `Content` suddenly contained a quotation mark, your JSON would be broken.

Comment: @mjwills m_host is "127.0.0.1:8888"
the value of json is : "{ \"Game\": \"zv\", \"Content\": {\"Call\": \"1\", \"Username\": \"\", \"Password\": \"\"} }"

Comment: @mjwills Ah yes that fixed the issue! Gave me another error but that's for another question :)
InvalidOperationException: Cannot override system-specified headers

If you add that as an answer i'll accept it once I have confirmed this next error has resolved it :)

Comment: @JamesVeug What will happen to your JSON if my password is `secret"password`?

Comment: @john password should never have un-escaped characters. However the server will reject it as it's invalid json.

Besides. Sending passwords over the network is the utter worst thing to do. This code is merely the groundwork to get it everything working before adding security

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON serializer instead of building it as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have failed to specify a URI scheme (like `http` or `https`).

Thus you must change:

```
127.0.0.1:8888
```

to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888
```